# como calcular o volume de armazenamento de um banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, entidade-relacionamento

É o seguinte, estou tendo preocupações a respeito de um banco de dados a ser utilizado num projeto. O projeto consiste no desenvolvimento de um software pra unir dados respectivos a dois sensores de espectro solar,e depois o armazenamento deles em um banco de dados em conjunto com outras informações de uma tabela "mestra". O conceito é que para cada linha na tabela mestre existirão milhares de linhas na tabela de espectro.

## RESUMO

Temos o seguinte diagrama:
[image: diagrama de entidades]

O problema que estou enfrentando é que as linhas da tabela mestre serão adicionadas 24/7 uma por minuto, e as linhas da tabela esp vão ser inseridas mais de mil por vez, mas somente 5 vezes por dia, com intervalo de uma hora.

## PROBLEMA

Pode ter ficado meio confuso, mas a preocupação maior não é entender esse diagrama.

O que quero fazer é calcular qual será o volume médio de dados que entrarão no banco por ano/mês/semana. existe alguma formula ferramenta ou maneira de calcular quanto espaço vou precisar pra armazenar esses dados?

desde já agradeço!

Comment: Isso muda de fabricante para fabricante. Especifique uma tag ou no texto qual é o SGBD que você está usando. Especifique também os índices porque eles também ocupam espaço.

Comment: Mas o fator do fabricante não vai ser muito levado em conta, porque após a leitura do sensor eu estou formatando os dados em python. no fim das contas quero estimar o armazenamento para todos os campos serem double, assim eu teria uma folga e depois calcularia a diferença correta. Não entendi o que você quis dizer cm índices, desculpe a falta de esperiência com banco de dados

Comment: A parte dos índices é porque cada índice ocupa espaço no banco de dados e aumenta conforme aumenta o número de linhas da tabela. Saber o fabricante também é importante, por exemplo, a query da resposta que foi postada funciona no Oracle mas não no MS SQL Server.

Comment: pensei que o fabricante mencionado seria o sensor, por isso disse que não faria diferença. No caso estou utilizando postgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa identificar o tamanho em bytes de cada linha. 
Com isso você conseguirá identificar, dado o numero de linhas da tabela, qual o tamanho da mesma.

No Oracle eu utilizo q query abaixo para obter o tamanho total da tabela e dividindo pelo numero de linhas obtenho o valor por linha e ai é seguir com a estimativa:

```
SELECT
   owner, 
   table_name, 
   TRUNC(sum(bytes)/1024/1024) Meg,
    ROUND(sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024, 2) GB,
   ROUND( ratio_to_report( sum(bytes) ) over () * 100) Percent
FROM
(SELECT segment_name table_name, owner, bytes
 FROM dba_segments
 WHERE segment_type IN ('TABLE', 'TABLE PARTITION', 'TABLE SUBPARTITION')
 UNION ALL
 SELECT i.table_name, i.owner, s.bytes
 FROM dba_indexes i, dba_segments s
 WHERE s.segment_name = i.index_name
 AND   s.owner = i.owner
 AND   s.segment_type IN ('INDEX', 'INDEX PARTITION', 'INDEX SUBPARTITION')
 UNION ALL
 SELECT l.table_name, l.owner, s.bytes
 FROM dba_lobs l, dba_segments s
 WHERE s.segment_name = l.segment_name
 AND   s.owner = l.owner
 AND   s.segment_type IN ('LOBSEGMENT', 'LOB PARTITION')
 UNION ALL
 SELECT l.table_name, l.owner, s.bytes
 FROM dba_lobs l, dba_segments s
 WHERE s.segment_name = l.index_name
 AND   s.owner = l.owner
 AND   s.segment_type = 'LOBINDEX')
WHERE UPPER( owner) in UPPER('MY_OWNER')
GROUP BY table_name, owner
HAVING SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 > 10  /* Ignore really small tables */
ORDER BY SUM(bytes) desc
```

Comment: Ótimo, era exatamente o que eu queria saber, então existe uma maneira, eu não sabia que dava pra verificar o tamanho das linhas assim. Meu banco ainda não foi populado, mas então eu vou popular ele um pouco e vou realizar alguns calculos antes de implementar totalmente.
talvez eu tenha diferenças de funções e querys por usar postgres mas acho que vou cnseguir. Muito obrigado